# Qual é o significado de "predicado" no contexto da computação?

Tags: terminologia, ciência-da-computação

Qual é a explicação do termo para a forma que é usada na programação/computação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Computação é matemática, aplicada de forma que facilite o uso com computadores de alguma forma (não necessariamente computadores modernos). Programação é uma parte disto, e é matemática. E programação é comunicação e expressão, é escrever textos que um humano entende bem.

É possível ver em algumas áreas da matemática que o termo é aplicado para a computação/programação: [lógica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)), [função com valor booleano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean-valued_function), [predicado sintático](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_predicate), [predicado funcional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_predicate) e [função proposicional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_function).

A função proposicional talvez seja o contexto mais usado em linguagens de programação. Em alguns casos o predicado funcional também pode ser muito usado, especialmente em linguagens declarativas.

Veja [na gramática](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(grammar)):

> O termo predicado é usado de duas maneiras na linguística e em seus subcampos. A primeira define um predicado como tudo em uma sentença declarativa padrão, exceto o sujeito, e a outra o vê apenas como o verbo de conteúdo principal ou expressão predicativa associada de uma cláusula. Assim, pela primeira definição, o predicado da frase *Frank gosta de bolo* é *gosta de bolo*. Pela segunda definição, o predicado da mesma sentença é apenas o verbo de conteúdo *gosta*, sendo que *Frank* e *bolo* são os argumentos desse predicado. As diferenças entre essas duas definições podem levar à confusão.

E podemos pegar o termo geral que serve para a computação:

> pre·di·ca·do (latim praedicatum, neutro de praedicatus, -a, -um,
> particípio passado de praedico, -are, proclamar, publicar, louvar,
> pregar) substantivo masculino
>
> 1. Propriedade característica de algo ou de alguém. = ATRIBUTO
> 2. Qualidade positiva. = DOTE, PRENDA, VIRTUDE
> 3. [Gramática]  Função  sintática desempenhada pelo grupo verbal (verbo, os seus complementos e modificadores) e que expressa algo
>    sobre o sujeito (ex.: nas frases seguintes, o predicado está
>    sublinhado: eu hoje acordei tarde; o quadro, felizmente, foi
>    recuperado ontem pela polícia; é muito agradável ter a lareira acesa).
> 4. [Lógica]  Termo ou conjunto de termos que se atribui, por meio de afirmação ou negação, ao sujeito de uma proposição.
>
> "predicado", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/predicado [consultado em
> 16-03-2023].

Na programação quase sempre o termo é usado pata indicar a expressão que determina se algo é verdadeiro ou falso. Em termos mais leigos é chamado de condição, mas o termo mais correto é predicado.

Em alguns contextos, como orientação a objeto, podem usar o termo mais gramatical e exigir que o predicado seja um método que usa um verbo para determinar se algo é verdadeiro ou falso, por exemplo em `frank.gostaBolo()` o método é o predicado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).